# Partial derivatives of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm trying to prove the following statement and I'm having a hard time. hopefully someone can give me some insight into how to approach it.

If $f$ is a polynomial divisible by n linearly-independent linear polynomials then the dimension of the vector space of partial derivatives of order $\frac{n}{2}$ is at least $\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}$.

Thanks.

Comment: So we are assuming $n$ is an even number, right?

Comment: Yes, it does.  .